# VB.NET Exposing child control properties

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

For a custom control I'm making, the datagridview is pretty much only going to be a customized version of the original. However, so that other controls I have made can interact with it, I have made it inherit my MetroControl class.

Since I cannot add multiple "Inherits", I have placed a DataGridView and docked it inside the control. From here I can then influence and theme it. Most of the properties are handled by my theming (such as the "RowHeadersStyle" etc..

I need to push forward the "Columns" property of the DataGridView so that the user can interact with the same column setup screen that they would as if they were using the normal DataGridView. Is there any way I can simply forward this property (as it would make it much easier for both me and the user)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a property on your UserControl that just returns the `Columns` property on the `DataGridView` (Assuming that your `DataGridView` is stored in field named `dataGridView`):

```
public DataGridViewColumnCollection Columns {
    get { return dataGridView.Columns; }
}
```

That's it

Comment: Its a read only property, I can get into the editor (then it complains about not having a cell template), when I run the program , the changes made to the datagridview just disappear